# How do i call different classes within in a class?

Tags: python, file, class, function, turtle-graphics

So I made two classes, one making a rectangle and one that makes a star, both being Rectangle() and Star() as there class taking in a specific amount of parameters.  My problem is that i have another class called Flag() that takes in a textfile that contain the specific parameters for each class, rectangle has 5 certain parameters, and star has 4.  I need the Flag class to read through the textfile and read through each line of the file, understand that each line is either a rectangle or a star, then draw it.

```
class Flag(object):
    def __init__(self, f_obj):
        self.f_obj = f_obj
        for line in self.f_obj:
            line.strip()
            if 5 == len(line):
                R = Rectangle(line)
                print(R)
            elif 4 == len(line):
                S = Star(line)
                print(S)

    def draw(self,turtle):
        R.draw(turtle)
        S.draw(turtle)
```

Comment: ........`from <wherever> import Flag`? is that what you're asking?

Comment: You'll probably want to call something like line.split()

Comment: i open a file 'file_obj' then i use that file in my main() and use the flag class to draw file_obj

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about file reading?
Try this:

```
parts = line.strip().split()
if len(parts) == 4:
    # Star
if len(parts) == 5:
    # Rectangle
```